# Ubuntu OpenVZ Kernel panic error when booting

Tags: linux-kernel, installation, ubuntu-14.04, panic, openvz

I want to use OpenVZ on my Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty platform. I installed the RHEL6 2.6.32 kernel (vzkernel_2.6.32-042stab093.5_amd64 kernel) following the instructions given in
    [Installing And Using OpenVZ On Ubuntu 13.04 (AMD64)](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-and-using-openvz-on-ubuntu-13.04-amd64)

When the machine is booted with the vzkernel_2.6.32, I get the following error:

"**Kernel panic - not sysncing: Fatal exception**"

and the boot freezes. However, I can interrupt the booting and select the original Ubuntu kernel and the machine boots fine.

Please see the attached screen shots.
[Screen shot of Kernel panic boot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjwZT.jpg)

Boot Menu:
imgur.com/5VjBZUj

Hardware: Dell PowerEdge T105 (quad core cpu, 8 GB RAM)

OS: Ubuntu 14:04 (Trusty) 64-bit

uname -r: 3.13.0-39-generic

I have installed the following components for the OpenVZ:

*ploop-1.12.1-1.x86_64.rpm

vzctl-core-4.8-1.x86_64.rpm
ploop-lib-1.12.1-1.x86_64.rpm

vzkernel-2.6.32-042stab093.5.x86_64.rpm
vzctl-4.8-1.x86_64.rpm

vzquota-3.1-1.x86_64.rpm*

I used the following steps for the installation:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i vz*.deb ploop*.deb

$ sudo vim /etc/default/grub
$ sudo update-grub

$ sudo update-rc.d vz defaults
$ sudo update-rc.d vzeventd defaults

$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libvzctl-4.8.so /usr/lib
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libploop.so.1.12.1 /usr/lib

$ sudo vi /etc/init.d/vz

Added the following:
$ sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf
[...]
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=1
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=1
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding=1
net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
kernel.sysrq = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.proxy_arp=1
[...]

$ sudo sysctl -p

$ sudo apt-get install vzdump
```

Any help in fixing this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OpenVZ uses a RHEL6 2.6.32 kernel as a basis. I doubt, that you could boot up Ubuntu 14.04 with one of the RHEL6 stock kernels, as Ubuntu 14.04 probably depends on newer kernel features not backported or even Debian/Ubuntu specific modifications.

If you want to try a OpenVZ-Kernel on your laptop, I suggest using a hypervisor like KVM, XEN or VirtualBox, or installing RHEL6/CentOS6/Debian6 on a separate partition.